# IEEE-754 double (64-bit floating point) vs. long (64-bit integer) revisited

Tags: java, javascript, double, long-integer, ieee-754

I'm revisiting a question ([How to test if numeric conversion will change value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601646)) that as far as I was concerned was fully solved. The problem was to detect when a particular numeric value would overflow JavaScript's IEEE-754 Number type. The previous question was using C# and the marked answer worked perfectly.

Now I'm doing the exact same task but this time in Java and it doesn't work. AFAIK, Java uses IEEE-754 for its `double` data type. So I should be able to cast it back and forth to force the loss of precision but it round trips. Baffled by this I started poking deeper in Java and now I'm really confused.

In both C# and Java, the min and max values for long are the same:

```
long MIN_VALUE = -9223372036854775808L;
long MAX_VALUE = 9223372036854775807L;
```

AFAIK, these values are outside the representable numbers in IEEE-754 because of the fixed bits reserved for the exponent and sign.

```
// this fails in browsers that have stuck with the pure ECMAScript Number format
var str = Number(-9223372036854775808).toFixed();
if ("-9223372036854775808" !== str) { throw new Error("Overflow!"); }
```

This returns `false` for (value = -9223372036854775808L) in Java:

```
boolean invalidIEEE754(long value) {
    try {
        return ((long)((double)value)) != value;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

This returns `false` for (value = -9223372036854775808L) in Java:

```
boolean invalidIEEE754(long value) {
    // trying to get closer to the actual representation and
    // being more explicit about conversions
    long bits = Double.doubleToLongBits(Long.valueOf(value).doubleValue());
    long roundtrip = Double.valueOf(Double.longBitsToDouble(bits)).longValue();
    return (value != roundtrip);
}
```

This returns `true` for (value = -9223372036854775808L) but is less accurate:

```
boolean invalidIEEE754(long value) {
    return (0x0L != (0xFFF0000000000000L & (value < 0L ? -value : value)));
}
```

Why does this work this way? Am I missing something like compiler optimization, e.g. is the compiler detecting my conversions and "fixing" them for me?

**Edit:** Adding test case by request. All three of these tests fail:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.Test;

public class FooTests {

    @Test
    public void ieee754One() {
        assertTrue(((long)((double)Long.MIN_VALUE)) != Long.MIN_VALUE);
    }

    @Test
    public void ieee754Two() {
        long bits = Double.doubleToLongBits(Long.valueOf(Long.MIN_VALUE).doubleValue());
        long roundtrip = Double.valueOf(Double.longBitsToDouble(bits)).longValue();

        assertTrue(Long.MIN_VALUE != roundtrip);
    }

    @Test
    public void ieee754Three() {
        long bits = Double.doubleToRawLongBits(Long.valueOf(Long.MIN_VALUE).doubleValue());
        long roundtrip = Double.valueOf(Double.longBitsToDouble(bits)).longValue();

        assertTrue(Long.MIN_VALUE != roundtrip);
    }
}
```

Comment: Both methods return `false` for me. JDK 1.6.0_21.

Comment: Interesting! Now I'm really confused. Mine is running via JUnit but should be on JDK 1.6.0_21 as well.

Comment: Can you show the full testcase?.

Comment: Sorry I had the true/falses swapped! Too many not-not's when talking about this. Sorry for the confusion. Your results are the same as mine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`-9223372036854775808L` **is** representable as an IEEE-754 double-precision number.  It is exactly `-2^63`, which has the double representation `-1.0 x 2^63` and encoding `0xc3e0000000000000`.

Double is capable of representing numbers much, much larger than this.  However, it is not capable of representing *all integers* in the range of representable numbers.  For example, if you add one to the number, you will get `-9223372036854775807 = -2^63 + 1`, which is *not* representable as a double-precision value, and will not survive the round-trip conversion.

Converting `-2^63 + 1` to double will round it to the nearest representable double value, which is `-2^63`; conversion back to long will preserve that value.

**Edit:** What platform did you do you JavaScript test on?  In current Safari,

```
"-9223372036854775808" === Number(-9223372036854775808).toFixed()
```

evaluates as `True`.

Comment: Also interesting. Sounds like I choose a bad test case! Why would it work in C# though? That confuses me.

Comment: @McKAMEY: If it actually "works" in C#, that's contrary to the IEEE-754 standard.  Have you observed this?

Comment: Yeah it was my test case and it "passed" :) Then I moved it over to Java and it wasn't.

Comment: Sweet. `(Long.MIN_VALUE+1)` and `(Long.MAX_VALUE-1)` work as expected. With simple casting. Now I'm concerned about the C# implementation...

Comment: @McKAMEY: I don't think that Microsoft claims C# adheres to IEEE-754, but that's pretty appalling.  I would file a bug report if you can't find a good reason for the misbehavior.

Comment: "Double complies with the IEC 60559:1989 (IEEE 754) standard for binary floating-point arithmetic." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.aspx

Comment: RE: the strict equals, I was converting both values to Strings. The toFixed() converts a JS Number to a String value.

Comment: @McKAMEY: Yeah, I see that now; I misread that part of your question initially.  Out of curiosity, what's the actual string generated by `Number(-9223372036854775808).toFixed()` on your system?  They compare equal in Safari, for example.  Also, I would definitely file a bug for the C# behavior you're seeing.

Comment: Safari 5.0 (7533.16) on Windows gives me `Number(-9223372036854775808).toFixed()` => "-9223372036854776000" as does IE8. Chrome 7.0.517.44 and Firefox 3.6.13 give me "-9223372036854775808". That rounding is specifically why I'm testing for this.

Comment: Chrome and Firefox have the (strict IEEE-754) correct behavior; given that Safari has the correct behavior on the Mac, it's probably relying on some system library that misbehaves on Windows.

Comment: To make things even more interesting, `double` does not have a perfect representation for the value of the largest `long`, but since the best `double` representation is greater than the largest `long`, and a cast back to `long` will be pegged at the largest `long`, the conversion will appear to have been correct.